# Rails 5 API Omniauth use ActiveRecord Session Store

Tags: ruby, api, activerecord, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently we are implementing a Rails 5 API with Omniauth and DeviseTokenAuth.

The initial portion seems to work great, however when attempting to validate the token and do anything further we get a CookieOverflow error. We deduced this was due to us storing >4KB of info from the Omniauth login.

We attempted to pivot to database stored sessions but continue to get errors from Omniauth

`NoSessionError: You must provide a session to use OmniAuth`

We are using

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
```

Our database migration is as follows

```
class AddSessionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.string :session_id, :null => false
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :sessions, :session_id, :unique => true
    add_index :sessions, :updated_at
  end
end
```

Lastly we did set up on the config/application.rb the session store

```
config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_my_app_session'
```

I'm not sure whyw e continue to get the error of you must provide a session to use OmniAuth. If we switch this back to a cookiestore

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

The app recognizes the session but throws the CookieOverflow error.

Comment: i would assume that you would need to use the middleware provided from the activerecord-session_store similiar to how you use the cookie store middleware. run `rake middleware` and make sure that the middleware is in the stack before omniauth. otherwise session will not be properly initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `config.api_only=false` în your application.rb file. The middleware for session store is only added If this is Set to false .

Adding the middleware manually doesn't work because the middleware is not instantiated în this case properly.

You can check the code from Rails here : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L58